# A date when a price is set by a company

Tags: word-choice

How would you call a date when a company sets its price? I. e. a carmaker will set the price for its new model on a certain date.

The context is a legal contract. In particular, does it sound right to say, "the date of new price setting" or "the date of the new price declaration"?

Comment: The price of a product.

Comment: Ok so, a carmaker will set the price for its new model on ...... Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, exactly

Comment: Please add those information in your question to clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: I doubt there is a specific way to say that, probably "price disclosure date" could fit.

Comment: In your example car the price is not set until you buy it An MSRP is assigned but customers are able to negotiate with the dealer. Also with many other cases a contract (cars, labor agreements) will need to finalized before the price is set. If you are talking about commercial retail (grocery store, clothing store) I do not think their a generic term, although there may be a legal one.

Comment: @Skooba Quite right. *Price* is something determined jointly by a willing seller in conjunction with a willing buyer. Whilst colour is fixed - anything you like so long as it's black. - *price lists* are totally irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe other SE sites could better answer this question. **Law** or **Economics**, perhaps, since you're looking for legal terms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a legal contract you have the power to define terms used in the contract. You can write something like this:

> For the purposes of this contract, the following definitions apply:
>
> > **Pricing Date**--means the date the price is set by...

Answer (score 0):

I think "price renewal date" would be used